# simple ng-click is not working in AngularJS. Is there anything basic that im missing here?

Tags: angularjs

Here is my aspx:

```
<body ng-controller="myController">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <input type="button" value="Press" ng-click="incrementCount()" ng-init="count=0"/>
        <span>{{ count }}</span>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

and following is JS:

```
    angular.module('myModule', [])
    .controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {  

    $scope.incrementCount = function () {
        $scope.count = $scope.count + 2;
    };
});
```

Whats wrong with my Code?? 
When I click the 'Press' button, it does not works as it should.

Comment: Everything should work, at least what you posted. Check that you defined `ng-app="myModule"` in DOM root

Comment: yes its already defined: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myModule">

Comment: well one problem is that you are using the $scope in the html, no need for that in this case. Also not sure why you put the function in the ng-click either. Only need that in the js file

Comment: @Daniel it was edit by some1 by mistake

Comment: @Daniel review the question again..

Comment: hmm looks much better now, is your controller loading at all?

Comment: May not be loading properly. How can i check that @dani

Comment: well you can initialize something in your controller, like $scope.test = "Test" and in your html do {{test}} somewhere and see if it prints out as it should. 

Another way is to get plugins for chrome for inspecting your scope and see what you have

Comment: On the output, i can see 'Press' button and '0' printed against it. The problem is when i click button, it does not increses the '0' to +2.

Comment: And yes, tried $scope.test = "Test", it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('myModule', []) .controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.incrementCount = function () {
    $scope.count = $scope.count + 2;
};
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myController">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <input type="button" value="Press" ng-click="incrementCount()" ng-init="count=0"/>
        <span>{{ count }}</span>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Its working normally ! Click RUN.

Comment: He has `ng-init="count=0"` inside HTML

Comment: @MaximShoustin updated .. without initializing variable in controller.

Comment: yes atulquest93, i have already initiated ng-init="count=0"
is there something wrong with that init???